# Problema para usar o click() do selenium em python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Olá, estou começando a usar o selenium. Comecei tentando acessar o google e alguns comandos básicos. Entretanto não consigo usar o click(). Meu programa:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class Google(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.url = 'http://google.com.br'
        self.search_bar = 'q'
        self.btn_search = 'btnK'
        self.btn_lucky = 'btnI'

    def navigate(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)

    def search(self):
        self.pesquisa = 'sabonete'
        self.driver.find_element_by_name(self.search_bar).send_keys(self.pesquisa)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('btnI').click()


gg = webdriver.Chrome()

g = Google(gg)

g.navigate()
g.search()
```

Erro:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

Answer (score 1):

Segundo A edureka! Communinity - [How do I resolve the ElementNotInteractableException in Selenium WebDriver](https://www.edureka.co/community/55217/resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-selenium-webdriver), ***ElementNotInteractableException*** ocorre quando o elemento é encontrado, mas não pode-se interargir com o elemento, não podendo enviar um click. Isso pode acontecer devido a vários motivos:

1. elemento pode não estar visível na tela ou não é mostrado na tela
2. elemento está fora da tela
3. elemento está atrás de outro elemento
4. elemento html está escondido (hidden="true")
5. o javascript da página ainda está "montando" a página e o botão ainda não apareceu na tela.

Reproduzi o problema aqui, a solução foi colocar um tempo de espera antes de tentar clicar no botão.

Exemplo:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_bar.send_keys('texto da pesquisa')
btn_lucky  = driver.find_element_by_name('btnI')
time.sleep(1)  # Aguarda 1 segundo antes de clicar, foi o suficiente para resolver o erro.
btn_lucky.click()
```

Provavelmente isso é causado pela forma que o Google monta os elementos na página de forma dinâmica com javascript, quando o selenium tenta clicar o botão ainda não foi renderizado na tela.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Realizei um teste e obtive o mesmo erro **"element not interactable"**.

Verifiquei que isso ocorre porque você não fechou o seu driver com o **driver.quit()**, dai o Chrome continua carregado na memória quando seu programa sai, e na próxima vez que você tentar executar o programa ele lança mais uma instância do Chrome, provavelmente o driver se perde e se conecta na instância errada do Chrome e começa a dar esse erro. Você deve sempre fechar o driver no final do seu programa para evitar problemas.

Para resolver o erro:

1. Primeiro mate todas as instâncias do chrome da memória com o comando `$ pkill chrome`
2. Coloque o comando `driver.quit()` no final do seu programa.
3. Execute novamente seu programa, ele deverá funcionar corretamente sem erro.

Comment: Sim. Isso foi proposital, eu não executei o `driver.quit()`, de propósito para o cara poder ver o resultado em tela, e fechar manualmente após verificar que o comando foi executado com sucesso. Eu posso editar minha resposta e deixar essa informação explícita.

Answer (score -1):

Nunca tentei interagir com uma página desta maneira, mas este erro que você está recebendo está dizendo que não é possível interagir com o elemento selecionado.

Uma maneira alternativa de conseguir o mesmo resultado é utilizando o elemento `input` da página inicial do google. Para isso basta pegar a `classe css` do elemento input da página.

Em meu exemplo utilizei o `xpath` para preencher os valores do `input text` e fazer o clique do botão `pesquisa do Google`

Segue um exemplo:

```
class Google(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.url = 'http://google.com.br'

    def navigate(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)

    def search(self):
        self.pesquisa = 'sabonete'
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(self.pesquisa)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]').click()



gg = webdriver.Chrome()

g = Google(gg)

g.navigate()
g.search()
```

Se precisar de ajuda, pode falar aqui.